# Cython buffer protocol example error

Tags: python, c++, cython

I am trying out the example at this url.  http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/buffer.html

To test it I do the following.

```
import pyximport
pyximport.install(build_dir = 'build')
import ctest

m = ctest.Matrix(10)
m.add_row()
print(m)
```

This gives me an error when I call the m.add_row() function saying
`TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

In the class add_row is defined as

```
from cpython cimport Py_buffer
from libcpp.vector cimport vector

cdef class Matrix:
    cdef Py_ssize_t ncols
    cdef Py_ssize_t shape[2]
    cdef Py_ssize_t strides[2]
    cdef vector[float] v

    def __cinit__(self, Py_ssize_t ncols):
        self.ncols = ncols

    def add_row(self):
        """Adds a row, initially zero-filled."""
        self.v.extend(self.ncols)
    ...
```

This error makes complete sense to me assuming calling extend on a vector in cython does exactly the same thing as does extend on a python list. You don't pass it a number but an iterable object which is append to the list.

I can fix it by doing this...

```
def add_row(self):
    """Adds a row, initially zero-filled."""
    self.v.extend([0] * self.ncols)
```

I was just wondering if there is a typo in the example or if I am missing something.  Also where does the extend function come from for the vector?  In the vector.pxd file distributed with cython it never imports the extend function and that does not even exist in the c++ standard library.  Does cython do something special with vector types?

https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/Cython/Includes/libcpp/vector.pxd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cpp `vector` can be automatically converted to a python list. By inspecting the c codes of the line `self.v.extend([0] * self.ncols)`, a new python list is created: `__pyx_t_2 = PyList_New(1 * ((__pyx_v_self->ncols<0) ? 0:__pyx_v_self->ncols))`. Thus `extend` is actually the `extend` method of python list.

Such automatic conversion can also be verified by following codes(in jupyter notebook):

```
%%cython -+
from libcpp.vector cimport vector

def test_cpp_vector_to_pylist():
    cdef vector[int] cv
    for i in range(10):
        cv.push_back(i)
    return cv

a = test_cpp_vector_to_pylist()
print a       # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
print type(a) # <type 'list'>
```

However, `cv` is converted to a temporary python list in such a case, the original cpp vertor will keep unmodified, as the following code shows:

```
%%cython -+
from libcpp.vector cimport vector

def test_cpp_vector_to_pylist_1():
    cdef vector[int] cv
    for i in range(10):
        cv.append(i)    # Note: the append method of python list 
    return cv

a = test_cpp_vector_to_pylist_1()
print a       # []
print type(a) # <type 'list'>
```

In addition, a c array can also be converted to python list automatically:

```
%%cython

def test_c_array_to_pylist():
    cdef int i
    cdef int[10] ca
    for i in range(10):
        ca[i] = i
    return ca

a = test_c_array_to_pylist()
print a       # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
print type(a) # <type 'list'>
```

Comment: It might be worth adding that the list doesn't get converted back to the vector, so the vector doesn't end up being extended.

Comment: That's right, add another code snippet to show that.